# Adding when solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a differential equation such as

$$(1+x^2)y' + xy = x+x^3$$

Am I allowed to add xy such that

$$(1+x^2)y' + 2xy = x(1+x^2+y)$$

and then solve for y by noticing that if $h(x) = 1+x^2$ then $h'(x)/2 = x$ and substituting.

Then

$h(x)y' + h'(x)y = x(1+x^2+y)$

So by product rule

$h(x)y = \int{x(1+x^2+y)}dx$

and then

$(1+x^2)y = x^2/2 + x^4/4 + x^2y/2$

So then

$y = x^2/2$

Why does this not work, am I changing the equation by adding the derivative to both sides?

Comment: You are definitely allowed to add $xy$ on both sides. The problem with your resolution is that when you integrate in $dx$, you are treating $y$ as a constant, but $y$ itself is a function of $x$ that has to be found, so you cannot explicitly solve the integral easily.

Comment: Hint: Instead of adding $xy$ to both sides of the equation, divide them by $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an error in calculation. Everything was fine until you went from

> h(x)y=∫x(1+x2+y)dx

(correct up to and on this line)

> and then
>
> (1+x2)y=x2/2+x4/4+x2y/2

(now incorrect)

Adding $xy$ to both sides at the beginning is perfectly fine and wasn't the problem. What you have to remember is that $y$ is a function of $x$ and so cannot pass right through the integral (like constants do) when performing $\int{xydx} \neq y\int{xdx} = x^2y/2$
Hope this answers your question.